# "Keep offset" connecting the wrong ends of the bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I am having trouble with the *Keep Offset* function that keeps on connecting the wrong ends of the bones together. As on this picture here, where the dotted line should link the two closest ends of the bones and not the farthest

[image]

Would you have the solution ?

Comment: You need to select the bones in the other order.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you answered your own question

Comment: When you answer your own question, and the answer is this simple, consider deleting the question so other people don't spend time reading it and contemplating an answer. Thanks.